# How to produce the 10 random numbers and create stars to indicate the value

Tags: java

So the question for my assignment is "Produce a horizontal star line that show your 10 variables from top to bottom as individual, distinct stars varying based on its value. For example, random number is 4, so I will have `****`.

This is what I did so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem01 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create random integer
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++ ){
            int random = ran.nextInt(20);
            //Printing the random number
            System.out.println("Number " + "(" + random + "): ");
        }
    }
}
```

I can generate 10 random number but I don't know how generate the stars, can you guys help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Create another loop just below the printline line.

for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {println ("*");}

Comment: Thanks a lot, Animesh Sahu, but I'm currently studying loops so the teacher asks me to use loops

Comment: Thanks, Abdullah Leghari, but I tried it and the * just appear in order like 1 star and then 2 star, but not a random number of stars to indicate random number

Comment: then do this. for(int j= 1; j <= random; j++)

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String generateStars(final int numberOfStars) {
   final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(numberOfStars);
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      sb.append("*");
   } 
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is only code. Youn intended to make your answer more upvotable by adding an explanation, didn't you?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm a newbie in Java so I don't really understand the code, I currently just started on loops so your code look a little complicated for me to understand

Comment: Strings addition are working differ than number addition. If your write 1 + 1, the result will be 2, but if you write "1" + "1" the result will be "11". Its called concatenation. So in this function we concatenate "*" with numberOfStars times. We use helper class StringBuilder, which is more efficient to build Strings.

Comment: [Please read [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Edit your answer and explain why it is the solution the the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Problem01 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create random integer
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++ ){
            int random = ran.nextInt(20);
            //Printing the random number
            System.out.println("Number " + "(" + random + "): ");
            
            for(int j = 1; j <= random; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output

```
Number (0):

Number (6):
******
Number (8):
********
Number (18):
******************
Number (17):
*****************
Number (0):

Number (7):
*******
Number (10):
**********
Number (14):
**************
Number (8):
********
```